Getting a list element value in Flutter/Dart
I am working and a project that contains a list obtained from a database. The database contains information about the tables in a resturant, the number of seats specifically.
I am using this class to load the information into my Flutter App:
import 'package:fap_0001_a/core/database.dart';

class Tables {
  var db = Database();

  Future<List<int>> getTableData(tableNumber) async {
    List<int> tableData;
    tableData = await db.getTableData(tableNumber);
    print(tableData);
    return tableData;
  }
}

And my database class is
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Database {
  late MySqlConnection conn;

  var settings = ConnectionSettings(
      host: 'hidden',
      port: hidden,
      user: 'hidden',
      db: 'hidden',
      password: 'hidden'
  );

  Database() {
    connectToDB();
  }

  Future connectToDB() async {
    try {
      conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  Future<List<String>> getSections() async {
    List<String> sections = <String>[];
    try {
      var results = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_sections');
      for (var row in results) {
        sections.add(row['colName']);
      }
    } catch (e) {}
    return sections;
  }

  Future<List<int>> getTableData(String tableNumber) async {
    List<int> seats = <int>[];
    var results = await conn
        .query('SELECT * FROM tbl_tables WHERE colName = ?', [tableNumber]);
    for (var row in results) {
      seats.add(row['colSeats']);
    }
    return seats;
  }
}

For odvious reason, I took out the connection settings in the code above. But rest assured  the app does connect to the database.
And finially I have the code I am trying to get to work:
import 'package:fap_0001_a/models/tables.dart';
import 'package:fap_0001_a/widgets/phoenix_button.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PhoenixTable extends StatelessWidget {
  final String tableNumber;
  final table = Tables();
  List<int> seats = <int>[];

  PhoenixTable({super.key, required this.tableNumber});

  loadTableData() async {
    seats = table.getTableData(tableNumber) as List<int>;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadTableData();
    print(seats);
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          '$tableNumber - ',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24,
          ),
        ),
        ...[
          for (var seat = 1; seat <= 2; seat++)
            PhoenixButton(
                tableNumber: (tableNumber), guestNumber: (seat.toString()))
        ],
        const SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 0,
            vertical: 0,
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 25,
            height: 20,
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: '  ',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text(' Send '),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

The getTableData method is run a single time and return a single number in a list for each table in the ground. The return values are:
[2]
[2]
[2]
[2]

In the spread operator I am using a loop to display a row of buttons.
Here is a picture of what I am looking for of the app running in my emulator:

What is am trying to do is have the app display a number of button at each table number. This button count would come from a database as explained earlier.
In the picture, the row of button is set to a hard value of 2, hence I get two buttons in a the row.
Now for what I have tried.
(For reference, this is the spread I am using to create the row of buttons):
...[
  for (var seat = 1; seat <= 2; seat++)
    PhoenixButton(
        tableNumber: (tableNumber), guestNumber: (seat.toString()))
],

As you can see with the hardcoded 2 in the for loop, I get two buttons. However, different table have different sizes, so I need the 2 to be a variable. I have tried changing the 2 to seats[0] thinking that would provide the value from the list.
I also tried assigning 2 to a variable name Test, on a global scale. And changed the 2 to Test in the spread, and that worked. But when I tried to assign the value from the loadTableData function I get a line with out any buttons.
And the thing that really frosts my cookies, is while I was making a change o try ro correct an error, I caught a glimpse of the emulator, and the app was working just fine. And I do not remember what I changed.
I hope I provided enough information about my problem. If you need more let me know, thanks in advance, Troy
After posting this question as a comment, I thought I would put it here.
Would useing a RestAPI solve this problem, because i am looking into that option as well.

check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEdw_1B7JHY,  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html and https://dart.dev/libraries/async/async-await for async stuff in general

 loadTableData(); You cannot have an async call like that in the middle of build.  build must run from beginning to end in 1/120th of a second to produce the next frame of your view.

You don't need to call the 'loadTableData()' within the build method. You can use a widget like 'FutureBuilder' for that. https://youtu.be/zEdw_1B7JHY
